# Jackson @RestController Spring force return duplicate nested object

Tags: spring, jackson

I have a List of objects with also nested objects, which I return as response in a Spring @RestController, example:

```
[{
          "id" : "10",
          "name" : "test",
          "createdBy" : {
            "id" : "10",
            "user" : {
              "id" : "55",
              "name" : "me"
            }
          }
    },
    {
          "id" : "13",
          "name" : "test 2",
          "createdBy" : 55
    }]
```

As you can see the first nested object is returned correctly, but the second time of the same object is returned only the id.

Now I'm wondering if there is a way to force Jackson to always resolve the nested object instead of returning only the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly this is not the default behavior. It only happens when there is a configured `@JsonIdentityInfo`.

Removing it will result in always serializing as full POJOs.

Beware of Jackson infinite loops when not using `@JsonIdentityInfo`.